# Typesetting variants of sum and integral signs in MathJax

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Is there any way to enforce the lower and upper limits of integrals and sums to appear below and above the respective signs in **MathJax** (cf e.g. the German variant described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_symbol and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170028/integral-sign-int)?

There doesn't seem be native support in **MathJax**, so I would appreciate suggestions for workarounds.

I need those variants for transcribing historical mathematical German texts and would also like to replicate the appearance of formulas as close as possible.

Comment: I you're looking to obtain this $\int\limits_0^1$ instead of this $\int_0^1 $, then just use "\limits" after "\int".

Comment: It seems that in centered formulas there is a difference between `\int_0^1 f(x) dx` and `\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx`. (Actually, I did not know this until know - I only saw that in the Wikipedia article you linked.) Here is the comparison: $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx \qquad \int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx.$$ I am not sure whether this is what you're trying to get. (In the previous comment, Zacky also used `\limits` to get similar effect in the inline mode.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'm trying to get what's on the right; at least for out of line formulas.

Comment: So I guess that the inline formulas you could try `$\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx$` $\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx$  or `$\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx$` $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx$. (Which is basically the suggestion from the first comment. Personally, I avoid \displaystyle in inline formulas, but probably this is a matter of taste and writing style.)

Comment: Zacky and Martin, thanks for the helpful feedback; would either of you add that to the MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top so that it doesn't get lost?

Comment: Also for in-line sums (and products, etc.) `\prod_{j=1}^5 T_j = \prod\limits_{j=1}^5 T_j` $\prod_{j=1}^5 T_j = \prod\limits_{j=1}^5 T_j$.  Also, in some styles of writing, we want ${}_a\!\int^b f(x)\;dx$.

Comment: For other signs (not integrals) something like this works too I guess: $\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}\sum}f(n)$, produced by "\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}\sum}f(n)". But I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: @ManfredWeis Well, \limits are already mentioned there,in [the answer about limits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/12850#12850). I am not sure, maybe something could be added to the [answer about displaystyle](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/25054#25054) I'll leave editing of the tutorial to others. The [MathOverflow Meta FAQ on MathJax](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3763/how-does-one-type-mathematical-formulas-on-this-site) has an example with sums.

Comment: @Zacky I think limits work just as fine with sums: `$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$` $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n$. Would you be willing to summarize some of the stuff mentioned in comments and post it as an answer?  BTW we can also discuss this [in the MathJax room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13752/2020/1/18), if we want to avoid too long discussion in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get the preferred notation in accordance with ISO 80000-2, use

```
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$
```

$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$

However, the following notations are also used

```
$$\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$

$$\sum\limits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum\nolimits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum {a_i}$$
```

$$\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {a_i}$$

$$\sum\limits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum\nolimits_i {a_i}$$

$$\sum {a_i}$$

Comment: \limits has no effect when the notation is displayed rather than inline. Thus: $$\sum_{i=1}^n$$ This is coded as \sum_{i=1}^n. What is the purpose of the {curly braces} where you wrote {a_i}? Omission of the braces yields the same result.

Answer (score 11):

This more-or-less summarizes some of the stuff which has already been said in the comments. If I understood correctly, the OP is asking about getting indices above/below the sign for integral or sum. I hope this answers the question at least partially.

Probably the best thing to do is to show some examples:

- In the inline mode we can write `$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$` or `$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$` to get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ or $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$. Similarly for integrals `$\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx$` vs. `$\int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx$` gives $\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx$ vs. $\int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx$
- In centered formulas, there is a difference for integrals, but not for sums. You can compare `$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$$` with `$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$$` and `R$\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx$` with `$$\int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx.$$`
  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n \qquad \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n\\ 
  \int_0^1 f(x) \;dx \qquad \int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx.$$
- In inline mode, you can also use `\displaystyle`. Again including/excluding `\limits` makes a difference for integrals, but not for sums. I'll leave the question, whether or not this is a good style of writing, to the people who know more about LaTeX and typography than I do. Still, I'll include the examples: `$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$` vs. `$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$` gives $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ vs. $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x_n$; `$\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx$` vs. `$\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx$` gives $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx$ vs. $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1 f(x) \;dx$.